# How can I remove the option of 'Save and Close' on the Survey sharepoint app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, survey

As above from the question, would like to find out if I'm able to remove the option, 'Save and Close' in the Survey app form?

Thank you!